# phonegap: login on local page and logout from remote page

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I've developped a phonegap App, using a local page for login and remote pages for the rest of App. 
The local page store login and password on localstorage, as remember me, to not type mail and password each time user open the App.

```
window.localStorage.email = $('#login-form [name="email"]').val();
window.localStorage.password = $('#login-form [name="password"]').val();
```

If user login the App call remote page through following code

```
if (data.success == 1) {
    window.location.href = url;
    return;
}
```

User can logout navigating on remote pages, but in order to do it I need to erase mail and password on localStorage. How can I achieve it ?

Comment: Suggestion: if you put `localStorage.removeItem('email');` in the remote page's logout, won't it work!!

Comment: I put localStorage.clear();, but din't work, I think it's like a crossdomain problem

Comment: `clear` has issues. try removeItem

Comment: it seems that localStorage of remote pages and local page are different. from remote page I can't removeItem('email') using localStorage.removeItem('email') it responds "undefined" but from local page I can. So my question is How clear from remote page localStorage setted by local page ?